# What are the states of the flip-flops after one clock pulse?

Tags: flipflop

[image]

It is given that Q0[MSB] and Q1[LSB] are both 0 initially and the circuit is edge triggered. The answer says this circuit will generate 2, but I am arriving at 3 and I can't see where I am going wrong.

My thought process is, initially Q0 and Q1 are 0, so the NAND gate will output one, therefore input to D will be 1. When the clock pulse is applied, 1 will pass through the D-Flip Flop and we will have Q0 = 1, now since Q0 is the input to the CLK of the T-Flip Flop and it has gone from 0 to 1, the T-Flip Flop will be activated, Q0 = 1 is also input to T, so it will toggle Q1 = 0 to Q1 = 1, and we will finally have Q0 = 1 and Q1 = 1, which is 3.

My instructor's explanation for arriving at 2:

"we always consider the initial states as the input to the flip-flops. The Q0n and Q1n are the next state values that we get as the output from the flip flop. Please don't get confused with this.

The input to the T-FF is Q0 and not Q0n.
For Q1 = Q0 = 0
Input to the D-FF is (Q0 . Q1)' = (0. 0)' = 1
This makes the Q0n = 1
But this Q0n is not the input to the T-FF.
Input to the T flip flop is Q0, and it will be active only when Q0 -> Q0n = 0 -> 1. Since for the case Q0 = Q1 = 0, Q0->Q0n is 0 -> 1, therefore, T-FF will be active.
Input to the T-FF is Q0 = 0, therefore, it will latch the Q1. Hence, Q1n = 0."

Comment: You may have to account for setup time and hold time.

Comment: @AJN is the question ambiguous, since nothing is mentioned? Or is there a common sensical assumption for setup and hold time?

Comment: To the second flip flop, the 1 appears at the same to `T` and clock. AFAIK, the input should appear slightly earlier than the clock edge. See [Timing section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) in this article. I am not sure though. Are these concepts taught by your instructor?

Comment: My instructor did tell me the definition of setup and hold time, didn't go into its significance in the actual example circuits though. I'm confused as hell about what's happening here to be honest, also, since you said the input must be present slightly earlier than the clock edge, does that mean I should take T = 0 when the T-Flip Flop is activated, because we have 0 as input right before the clock pulse.

Comment: Yes. `T=0`. But, I would either *1)* wait for someone to answer this question where it is accounted for, or *2)* try to do a simulation that takes this into account or *3)* look up a text book where a problem which takes this into account is worked out clearly. Especially since a answer containing a simulation result is posted which says otherwise.

Comment: Understandable, I'm looking up university slides/textbooks for a similar question. I'm gonna edit in my teacher's explanation if you/anyone else is curious.

Comment: no number is generated ... the circuit has no outputs ... perhaps you should be asking `what are the states of the flip-flops after one clock pulse?`

Comment: @jsotola, thank you for your suggestion, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instructor is saying that the next state will be Q0 = 1, Q1 = 0 (which is not “2” by the way).

Based on your instructor’s explanation, I think what’s happened here is the diagram is drawn wrong: the clk was intended to be connected to the clock input of both flip flops. The explanation would then be correct: the T flip flop’s clk edge would occur while Q0n was still 0 so its output would remain 0.

The way it’s drawn (T and clk tied together) there is a likely metastable condition where the output is indeterminate because of setup/hold violations, which I’m sure was not an intended aspect of this question.

Comment: Agreed. It’s almost certainly drawn wrong.

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding this correctly, the problem with this circuit is that the input to the flip flop is changing simultaneously along with clock, and if we have a common clock, as you suggested, that problem is eliminated, here, the inputs change after the clock pulse.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. With a common clock it is a standard synchronous design: both flops see the clock edge at the same instant, and the state of D (or T) at that point determines the next state. It takes some finite time to propagate D (or T) to Q. By the time Q0 changes the clock edge has come and gone on the T flop. Having the D (or T) change at exactly the same time as the clock is a worst case scenario: the output is unpredictable.

Comment: Thank you for more details and your answer, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be three as you clearly explained. I have done the simulation in Logisim which also gives three after one clock pulse.[image]

Comment: I think you're confusing T-Flip Flop with a NOT gate. For T=1, T flip-flop toggles Q, for T=0, it retains Q.

Comment: In your figure, T will be 1 at the first clock pulse.

Comment: Yes, I agree, since T would be 1 and Q1 is 0, shouldn't it toggle Q1 to 1?

Comment: I don't think so, the state of the second flip flop, as represented by Q1, is given to be 0 initially, whatever happens after the first clock pulse, the previous state of the Q1 would be 0, but I'm no expert, so I may be wrong.

Comment: I think that the answer should be three in every way.

Comment: I think so too, I even did a simulation that confirms it, but my teacher wouldn't agree. His rationale for 2 is that, T = Q0, initially Q0 is 0, so we will have T = 0, therefore no toggling occurs and Q1 remains 0, I don't understand how it doesn't matter that Q0 has actually changed to 1.

Comment: Which book are you using? He is obviously wrong.

Comment: None, sadly, I have to stick to video lectures because of time constraints.

Comment: Wow, thanks for doing the simulation and all the time and effort you put in, I appreciate it man.

Comment: There is a book called "Digital Design with an introduction to Verilog HDL" by Morris Mano and Ciletti which is very good for beginners. There are various practice problems too .

Comment: Alright, I'll look into it, thank you so much again.

Comment: What are setup time and hold time for each flip flop you are you using in the simulator?

Comment: @tim mine doesn't have that much customization (I'm using logic simulator pro on Android), but it says "elements latency" is 16ms and the clock is at 0.5Hz, if that's of any relevance.